# Style of editable false TextInput on Android

Tags: react-native

On Android, if I set `editable` prop to `false`, it grays out, or lowers opacity of the content. I want it to not do this, I want no difference between the two. Is there anyway to style the editable false input? I know I can wrap it in pointer-events none view, but this is a workaround)

Here is code and screenshot:

```
        <TextInput
         style={styles.inputs}
         value="This is enabled TextInput" />

        <TextInput
         style={styles.inputs}
         value="This is disabled TextInput"
         editable={false} />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This feature cannot be modified.
The only solution for now is to

1. Create a `View`, make it absolute to the `<TextInput />` element
2. Set the `width` and `height` of the view to `"100%"` and the `left` and `top` to `0`
3. Make the background `"transparent"`
4. Make it a reusable component and take in `editable` as **props** so as to render when needed

Here's the Snippet:

```
const CustomInputWithEditable = ({editable == true}) => {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        position: 'relative',
        width: '100%',
     }}>
        <TextInput
          keyboardType={type || 'default'}
          style={{ //Your custom style}}
          //add your own custom props
        />
        {
          editable == false &&
          <View style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
          }}>
          </View>
        }
    </View>
  )
}
```

That's it...Don't forget to import what's needed.

Comment: Thanks, I actually think I fixed it, by setting `color: 'black'` in the `style` prop of the `<TextInput>`